# Highlight Android NDK error output

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is there tool that adds highlighting to android ndk build output (may be on stderr).

e.g. If it will highlight word "error:" in red and "Warning:" in orange that would be what I look.

But if it will also give different colors to code and error messages then it would be awesome!

**ANSWER**

```
red=$(tput setaf 1)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
norm=$(tput sgr0)

$ANDROID_NDK/ndk-build  2>&1 | sed -e "s/\(error:\)/${red}\1${norm}/i" | sed -e "s/\(warning:\)/${yellow}\1${norm}/i"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this by piping the output of your build command (or any other terminal command) to sed:

```
red=$(tput setaf 1)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
norm=$(tput sgr0)
make | sed -e "s/\b\(error:\)\b/${red}\1${norm}/i" | sed -e "s/\b\(warning:\)\b/${yellow}\1${norm}/i"
```

Comment: Metacharacters support in sed is (apparently) only in GNU sed, if you have a version from another provider, it may not support them. I tested these with GNU sed v4.2.2, and they work. `\b` is the metacharacter for a word boundary. Without it, you will match strings that containing 'error:' and 'warning:'. This might not be a big issue for you, because those kinds of strings are probably rare in build output.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14.04 with default `sed`. Thank You for your help!